# Setting a default Apache RewriteRule entry

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, default-value

I want to set a 'default' rewrite rule to catch anything that didn't match the previous rewrite entries. I've tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

But the output returned is:

```
url = index.php
```

Ideally what I want is to attach all the GET values to 'url' so they will be saved to my web log. Anyone have any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omit needless parentheses in regular expressions whenever you can:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [L]
```

If you want to exclude "index.php":

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php).* index.php?url=$0 [L]
```

Comment: Apache 1.x doesn't use the PCRE library.

Answer (score 3):

You need to exclude the destination from your rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove slash:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```