# What's wrong with this htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to use this .htaccess file in an mvc project  to redirect everything  to the index page/controller/method/params  but when I go to the root directory I get a 500 error.  Is there something wrong with the code:

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 9999

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mvc/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: it could be an infinite loop, redirecting to a url (index.php) that matches the pattern. You might want to exclude index.php in your RewriteRule regex. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1855345/1165635

Comment: Could you please copy the lines in your apache error log related to the Internal Server error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PHP as CGI, you can't use the php_flag and php_value settings.

[Reference](http://support.tigertech.net/php-value)